# Find the possible values of $P$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given $Pr(A) = 0.3, Pr(B) = 0.4$, and $Pr(A'|B') = \frac{10p^2-1}{6}$,
find the possible values of $p$.

From what I know(using the conditional probability formula):
$$Pr(A'|B')= \frac{Pr(A'\cap B')}{Pr(B')}$$

$$Pr(A'\cap B') = \frac{10p^2 -1}{10}$$

I need help after this step.

Comment: Your title and work are contradictory. Are you saying $P(A'\cap B')=P(A'|B')$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Pr(A'  \cap B')$=$1-Pr(A \cup B)$=$1-[0.4+0.3-Pr(A \cap B)]$

=$0.3+Pr(A \cap B)$

Hence on simplification, we get $p^2=0.4+Pr(A \cap B)$.

Also, $0<Pr(A \cap B)<min[Pr(A),Pr(B)]=0.3$

Hence, $0.4<p^2<0.7$. So, you get all possible values of $p^2$, and hence $p$.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the process. I just had a question. 
What does (min[Pr(A), Pr(B)]) refer to?

Comment: It refers to the lesser one of the two( P(A) and P(B)).